# How to use text from the url query string to populate the image name in the image src path?

Tags: jquery, html

I am very new to js and teaching myself from all the amazing people on your site. Thanks to code on this site I have worked out how to populate text on my web page from parameters pulled from the query string in the url, but I cannot work out how I use the same parameters to populate the file name in an image path.

example url: http://www.mywebpage.com/editors.aspx?config=pagename&FirstName=Joe&LastName=Bloggs

What I have so far that works to populate text on the page:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">  

            $(document).ready(function(){  

            function getUrlVars()  
            {  
                var vars = [], hash;  
                var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');  
                for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)  
                {  
                    hash = hashes[i].split('=');  
                    vars.push(hash[0]);  
                    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];  
                }  
                return vars;  
            }  

            var brokerFirstName = getUrlVars()["FirstName"];  
            var brokerLastName = getUrlVars()["LastName"];  

            $('.BrokerFirstName').replaceWith(decodeURI(brokerFirstName));  
            $('.BrokerLastName').replaceWith(decodeURI(brokerLastName));  


            });  

            </script>  

            <html>  
            <div class="detailstext"><span class="BrokerFirstName">first name</span>&nbsp;<span class="BrokerLastName">last name</span>  
            <img src="/library/profileimages/????????????????.jpg">  
            </div>
```

How do I get the firstname and lastname into the src path for the image name, eg, src="/library/profileimages/JoeBloggs.jpg"?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Give your img tag an ID then select the image with jquery and then use .attr() like so:

```
$(#imgId).attr("src", "/library/profileimages/" + brokerFirstName + brokerLastName + ".jpg")
```

(replace 'imgId' with the id you gave to the img tag)

Comment: Perfect - works exactly how I need it to. Thank you!